# What is the Interface "any" that I can see with Wireshark, and is it safe

Tags: networking, interface, ubuntu-mate

As you can see in the image-- interface loopback and interface any are running all the time. In my understanding loopback is to communicate internally with applications.

But not sure what interface "any" is for with "Encapsulation type: Linux cooked-mode capture". 
Could it be the Java plug-in? I do have Fruho vpn manger installed but not running.

`$ ifconfig` only shows two interfaces Loopback and wired or wireless.

```
$ uname -a:
HP-Pavilion-dv2700-Notebook-PC 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:41:41 UTC 2016 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

dpkg -s network-manager | grep 'Version'  
Version: 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
```

[image: wireshark]

Comment: 'any' is a Wireshark built in that listens on all available interfaces.  It doesn't exist as an actual device, and if you have a lot of traffic over multiple interfaces then you will see a ton of data possibly duplicated.  You won't be able to tell clearly though what is coming over what interface though.

Comment: This link shows packets from both interfaces 'enp0' and 'any' https://yadi.sk/d/ijcJx24pvftAc

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is more clearly explained in `man wireshark`, but `Any` is used on systems with more than 1 interface, e.g. `eth0`, `eth2`, `wlan0`, like my firewall.

Comment: I think this explains when it's shown but not what it does...

Comment: The `Any` is a simulated interface that "sees" all packets on any interface, while if I select `eth0` instead, I'll see `eth0` packets, but not `eth2` or `wlan0` packets.